# iphone sdk initWithNibName gets called multiple times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to load view controllers dynamically just by specifying their names, but the problem is the initWithNibName method gets called twice so i can't rely on it to do initializations. It's a late night so i might just be missing something. Below is the code i use to load the controller, maybe you'll spot the error here:

```
/*
 Loads a view from a nib file. The parameter of this method is a nib name 
 withoug an extension (eg. MyView). A controller for the view must exist
 with the same name + "Controller" (eg. MyViewController)
 */
+(UIViewController *)loadViewFromNib:(NSString *)nibName
{
    // Try to create an object by class name
    // We need this so that the controller-specific overriden methods could be called
    Class ctrlClass = NSClassFromString([nibName stringByAppendingString:@"Controller"]);
    NSObject *customctrl = [ctrlClass new];
    UIViewController *ctrl = (UIViewController *)customctrl;
    // Init the controller
    [ctrl initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    [[ctrl view] setHidden:NO];
    [ctrl autorelease];
    return ctrl;
}
```

Thank you for your thoughts

Comment: If you remove `[ctrl initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
` is it called at all, once or still twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it is.

This is your problem:

```
NSObject *customctrl = [ctrlClass new];
UIViewController *ctrl = (UIViewController *)customctrl;
[ctrl initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
```

`+new` is a synonym for `alloc`/`init`.  `-[UIViewController init]` simply calls `-initWithNibName:bundle:` with `nil` as both arguments.  You're then calling it yourself.

In other words, you're initializing your object twice, which is a BIG no-no.  Here's what you want instead:

```
UIViewController *ctrl = [[ctrlClass alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You are absolutely right, i didn't even know about this behaviour of tne "new" keyword. Thanks a lot!